# Call a class function is undefined

Tags: php

Actually learning the PHP language, I have a problem when I'm calling a function from a class, I got the "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function" whereas I've included my external file.

Here are my 2 files :

** The external class that I want to call:**

```
<?php

class DBClass {


//Get the database connection
public function GetConnection()
{
  ...
}
?>
```

**My caller file :**

```
<?php
include_once './dbclass.php';
try{
    $dbclass = new DBClass();
    $connection = $dbclass.GetConnection();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I got that error when I'm calling the GetConnection function, any idea?

Comment: In PHP you access an object property with `->`, not `.`. Try `$connection = $dbclass->GetConnection();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
include_once './dbclass.php';
try{
    $dbclass = new DBClass();
    $connection = $dbclass->GetConnection();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

try the above code...
in PHP we use -> to call methods of class...

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions which are just simple typos. Instead, make a comment (as I have already done) and flag the question as "off-topic" due to a non-reproducible or typographical error. Questions like this add no value to the site and will eventually be deleted, thus causing you to lose any reputation that you may gain from answering.